# Problem in installing miktex

Tags: errors, miktex

While installing miktex this issue was detected and then when I want to build my pdf in tex studio it gave an error for not finding the packages. After I want to install them the error no ssl connection is appeared. Please see the attached[image]

Comment: This doesn't show an error (but it tells you that you should check for update in admin mode). What happens if you click on "Next"?

Comment: nothing it says that install finished!!

Comment: ssl connect error is the main error

Comment: are you behind a proxy or similar? Did you try to change to another repository?

Comment: proxy? No. It was working till yesterday then i update suddenly and this was happaened!